# How can make skype clone with delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, skype

How make program like skype,?
What should I have to know to make it like the program?
Which component should I use?

Comment: And don't forget that Skype is more than just tje Windows client. You will also need some backend servers to connect the clients!

Comment: thankyou very much... how to make server and client skype as usual?

Comment: What do you already have / know?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, Skype is written in Delphi and uses [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org) for its network communications.  You will have to implement the actual audio/video protocols manually.